# How i can create a .ppt file from as3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, powerpoint, actionscript-3

How i can create a .ppt file from as3? i need to add one image to powerpoint and save the .ppt file on a button click. Is there any as3 library available for saving files as ppt?
Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can use the fact, that any Ofice document is saved as a ziped set of XML files. You can just look at the structure of your ppt. Then you can use a zip-library for flex to pack and unpack it and to manipulate the content. Have a look at this post for more information (it's an example for Excel diagrams) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722645/export-flex-chart-and-datagrid-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

I write VBA code in Microsoft Office PowerPoint for you. You can achieve to your goal with this code.

You must create a text file with name "Info.txt" in following order when you want to create a PowerPoint presentation (path of the text file must be in where you have placed my attached "InsertPicture-Office 2007.pptm" and "InsertPicture-Office 2010 & 2013.pptm" files):

Line 1. Distance of the image from Left of the slide

Line 2. Distance of the image from Top of the slide

Line 3. Image Width in the slide

Line 4. Image Height in the slide

Line 5. Full path and name (with extension [.pptx]) for saving PowerPoint presentation file

Line 6. Full path and name (with extension) of an image for inserting in the slide of the PowerPoint presentation

After save the text file, you only must run the "InsertPicture-Office 2007.pptm" or "InsertPicture-Office 2010 & 2013.pptm" file and everything will be done.

Remember that you must "Enable all macros" for Microsoft Office PowerPoint from following way:

Open Microsoft Office Powerpoint -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> Enable all macros ...

[4Shared -> InsertPicture-Office 2007.pptm, InsertPicture-Office 2010 & 2013.pptm and Info.txt files](http://www.4shared.com/zip/aq2fjc7S/InsertPicture.html)

[SendSpace -> InsertPicture-Office 2007.pptm, InsertPicture-Office 2010 & 2013.pptm and Info.txt files](http://www.sendspace.com/file/3xlfzd)

You can test it only with change "Info.txt" file in order of what I'm mentioned above, and opening one of the "InsertPicture-Office 2007.pptm" or "InsertPicture-Office 2010 & 2013.pptm" files according to installed version of the Microsoft Office PowerPoint in your system.